# _CastError (type '' is not a subtype of type 'Category' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

> *CastError (type '*$_Order' is not a subtype of type 'Category' in type cast)

My error is here

```
var category = categories[index]
```

That my code

```
class OrderWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const OrderWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: _odersList(ref),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget _odersList(WidgetRef ref) {
    final orders = ref.watch(
      ordersProvider(
        PaginationModel(page: 1, pageSize: 10),
      ),
    );
    return orders.when(
        data: (list) {
          return _buildOrderList(list!.cast<Order>(), list.cast<Category>(),
              list.cast<Data>(), ref);
        },
        error: (_, __) => const Center(
              child: Text("ERR"),
            ),
        loading: () => const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ));
  }

  Widget _buildOrderList(List<Order> orders, List<Category> categories,
      List<Data> users, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Container(
      height: 500,
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: orders.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var order = orders[index];
          var category = categories[index];
          var user = users[index];

          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    order.orderName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 120,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 212, 209, 206),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  user.fullName,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  category.categoryName,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Ngày đặt bàn: 26/3/2023",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Ngày bắt đầu tiệc: 29/3/2023",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  order.orderDescription,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 0, 0, 80),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 10,
                                height: 10,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 255, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does:

```dart
          return _buildOrderList(list!.cast<Order>(), list.cast<Category>(),
              list.cast<Data>(), ref);
```

`list!.cast<Order>()`, `list.cast<Category>()`, and `list.cast<Data>()` cannot all succeed unless every element of `list` derives from `Order` *and* `Category` *and* `Data`.

"Casting" in Dart does not transform data; it does not construct new objects.  Casting only changes the perceived type of an object.

If you need to apply a transformation to create new `Order`, `Category`, and `Data` elements, use [`List.map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/ListBase/map.html) or use collection-`for`.

Comment: Please! can you help me fix this, i don't know how to fix it yet

Comment: @ChiếnTrần I can't help you further since you haven't provided code that reproduce the problem.  I don't know what the `Order`, `Category`, and `Data` types are.  I don't know what objects are in `list` or what you intend to do with them.   You need to figure that out on your own.